# Persona Xtradb cluster CONFLICT DETECTED

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster, xtradb-cluster

I am working on a high-traffic platform with MySQL clustering using Percona XtraDB Cluster. I have a cluster consisting of 4 nodes. The database is receiving more than 500 requests per second for inserting, selecting, and updating data on the same tables. Below is my MySQL configuration:

```
[mysqld]
######## START General settings ###############

# General settings
user = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
mysqlx_socket=/tmp/xplugin.sock
port = 3306
basedir = /usr
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
bind-address   = 192.168.100.20
log-error-verbosity=3
innodb_redo_log_capacity=2147483648
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci

auto_increment_increment = 5  
auto_increment_offset = 3  



############################## END General settings ##############################



############################## START wsrep ##############################
#-
server-id=2
# Path to Galera library
#-
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera4/libgalera_smm.so
# Cluster connection URL contains IPs of nodes
#If no IP is found, this implies that a new cluster needs to be created,
#in order to do that you need to bootstrap this node
#-
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.100.2,192.168.100.1,192.168.100.20,192.168.100.21

# In order for Galera to work correctly binlog format should be ROW
#-
binlog_format=ROW

# Slave thread to use
#-
wsrep_slave_threads=16
#-
wsrep_log_conflicts

# This changes how InnoDB autoincrement locks are managed and is a requirement for Galera
#-
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2

# Node IP address
#-
wsrep_node_address=192.168.100.20

# Cluster name
#-
wsrep_cluster_name=pxc-cluster

#If wsrep_node_name is not specified,  then system hostname will be used
#-
wsrep_node_name=pxc-cluster-node-3

#pxc_strict_mode allowed values: DISABLED,PERMISSIVE,ENFORCING,MASTER
#-
pxc_strict_mode=ENFORCING

# SST method
#-
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup-v2
#-
pxc_encrypt_cluster_traffic = OFF

############################## END wsrep ##############################

# Number of CPU cores
innodb_read_io_threads = 16
innodb_write_io_threads = 16
innodb_thread_concurrency = 16
innodb_purge_threads = 4
innodb_page_cleaners = 4
innodb_log_write_ahead_size=4
thread_cache_size = 64
#thread_handling = pool-of-threads
thread_handling = one-thread-per-connection

# Buffer pool size (assuming 128GB RAM)
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 100G


# Storage device type
innodb_io_capacity = 1500 # Adjust for NVMe SSD
innodb_io_capacity_max = 3000 # Adjust for NVMe SSD


############################## START Performance settings ##############################

default_storage_engine = InnoDB
key_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 16
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90
innodb_flush_neighbors = 0
innodb_lru_scan_depth = 4096
innodb_change_buffer_max_size = 50
innodb_adaptive_hash_index = 0
innodb_doublewrite = 0
innodb_flush_sync = 0
innodb_max_undo_log_size = 2G
innodb_use_native_aio = 0
innodb_undo_log_truncate = ON

############################## END Performance settings ##############################


############################## Start Connection setting ##############################

# Connection settings
max_connections = 3000
max_allowed_packet = 256M
wait_timeout = 600
interactive_timeout = 600

############################## END Connection setting ##############################

############################## START Logging settings ##############################



log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
long_query_time = 5
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 1
log_slow_admin_statements = 1
log_slow_replica_statements = 1

############################## END Logging settings ##############################
```

However, I am facing an issue with "CONFLICT DETECTED" And LOCK issue on my nodes, and the following errors are being reported:

```
2024-01-12T22:52:49.382682Z 16 [Note] [MY-011825] [InnoDB] *** WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
2024-01-12T22:52:49.382697Z 16 [Note] [MY-011825] [InnoDB]  SQL1:
2024-01-12T22:52:49.382711Z 16 [Note] [MY-011825] [InnoDB]  SQL2: INSERT INTO `requests_log` .....
2024-01-12T22:52:49.382739Z 16 [Note] [MY-000000] [WSREP] --------- CONFLICT DETECTED --------
2024-01-12T22:52:49.382756Z 16 [Note] [MY-000000] [WSREP] cluster conflict due to high priority abort for threads:

2024-01-12T22:52:49.382768Z 16 [Note] [MY-000000] [WSREP] Winning thread:
   THD: 16, mode: high priority, state: exec, conflict: executing, seqno: 177984003
   SQL: (null)

2024-01-12T22:52:49.382781Z 16 [Note] [MY-000000] [WSREP] Victim thread:
   THD: 2338759, mode: local, state: exec, conflict: certifying, seqno: -1
   SQL: INSERT INTO `requests_log` ......
2024-01-12T22:52:49.407148Z 2338784 [Note] [MY-011825] [InnoDB] *** Lock requesting TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 255572069, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
, undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 2338784, OS thread handle 139937898251840, query id 37507384 wsrep: writing row for write-set (177984004)
2024-01-12T22:52:49.407423Z 2338784 [Note] [MY-011825] [InnoDB] *** Lock holder TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 255572067, ACTIVE (PREPARED) 0 sec
, undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 16, OS thread handle 140003591190080, query id 37507363 wsrep: preparing to commit write set(177984003)
2024-01-12T22:52:50.780305Z 21 [Note] [MY-011825] [InnoDB] *** Priority TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 255572175, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT , undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 21, OS thread handle 139994867009088, query id 37507865 wsrep: writing row for write-set (177984088)
2024-01-12T22:52:50.780456Z 21 [Note] [MY-011825] [InnoDB] *** Victim TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 255572174, ACTIVE 0 sec, thread declared inside InnoDB 4999
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
, undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 2338797, OS thread handle 139937889797696, query id 37507862 192.168.100.20 mixsimverify wsrep: replicating and certifying write set(-1)
update `users` set `balance`= ....
2024-01-12T22:52:50.780515Z 21 [Note] [MY-011825] [InnoDB] *** WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
2024-01-12T22:52:50.780530Z 21 [Note] [MY-011825] [InnoDB]  SQL1:
2024-01-12T22:52:50.780545Z 21 [Note] [MY-011825] [InnoDB]  SQL2: update `users` set `balance`= .....
2024-01-12T22:52:50.780564Z 21 [Note] [MY-000000] [WSREP] --------- CONFLICT DETECTED --------
2024-01-12T22:52:50.780588Z 21 [Note] [MY-000000] [WSREP] cluster conflict due to high priority abort for threads:

2024-01-12T22:52:50.780606Z 21 [Note] [MY-000000] [WSREP] Winning thread:
   THD: 21, mode: high priority, state: exec, conflict: executing, seqno: 177984088
   SQL: (null)

2024-01-12T22:52:50.780624Z 21 [Note] [MY-000000] [WSREP] Victim thread:
   THD: 2338797, mode: local, state: exec, conflict: certifying, seqno: -1
   SQL: update `users` set `balance`= ......

2024-01-12T22:52:50.802889Z 2338810 [Note] [MY-011825] [InnoDB] *** Lock requesting TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 255572178, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
MySQL thread id 2338810, OS thread handle 139937889797696, query id 37507868 Applying batch of row changes (update)
2024-01-12T22:52:50.803030Z 2338810 [Note] [MY-011825] [InnoDB] *** Lock holder TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 255572175, ACTIVE (PREPARED) 0 sec committing
, undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 21, OS thread handle 139994867009088, query id 37507865 innobase_commit_low (177984088)
2024-01-12T22:52:51.291489Z 12 [Note] [MY-011825] [InnoDB] *** Priority TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 255572217, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT
MySQL thread id 12, OS thread handle 140007278396992, query id 37508017 Applying batch of row changes (update)
2024-01-12T22:52:51.291632Z 12 [Note] [MY-011825] [InnoDB] *** Victim TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 255572216, ACTIVE 0 sec, thread declared inside InnoDB 4999
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
, undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 2338798, OS thread handle 139954061203008, query id 37508015 192.168.100.20 mixsimverify wsrep: replicating and certifying write set(-1)
update `users` set `balance`= ....
2024-01-12T22:52:51.291691Z 12 [Note] [MY-011825] [InnoDB] *** WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
2024-01-12T22:52:51.291707Z 12 [Note] [MY-011825] [InnoDB]  SQL1:
2024-01-12T22:52:51.291751Z 12 [Note] [MY-011825] [InnoDB]  SQL2: update `users` set `balance`= ....
2024-01-12T22:52:51.291779Z 12 [Note] [MY-000000] [WSREP] --------- CONFLICT DETECTED --------
2024-01-12T22:52:51.291798Z 12 [Note] [MY-000000] [WSREP] cluster conflict due to high priority abort for threads:
```

How can I address and resolve this conflict and the LOCK issue?

Comment: hmmm...  5 nodes yet `auto_increment_increment = 5`

Comment: Were you involved in making "priority" transactions?

Comment: I can't understand what you mean @RickJames

Comment: I am not familiar with the term "priority transaction"; perhaps it is something that Galera came up with.

Comment: I believe there is an issue when two requests arrive simultaneously and both need to update the same record in the database, such as the balance field in the users' table. In this scenario, both requests have high priority, but Persona does not have the ability to execute two transactions concurrently on the same field.
I am encountering deadlock issues occasionally due to this limitation.

Comment: PXC (Galera) solves such collisions by having your `COMMIT` fail.  Your program _must_ check for errors in Commit.  And, with 4 nodes and 500/sec, there _will be_ occasional errors.

Comment: Please provide the code for the full transaction (`BEGIN` thru `COMMIT`) that each of the 2(?) nodes ran.  (Possibly they were the same code.)